# Mini questions on 'unsigned char' and 'shift' operation?

Tags: c++, c

The question should be basic but i am surprised that i had some trouble get it now. First one is when i glanced 'C++ primer' book chapter 5.3. The Bitwise Operators, when author use below code as an example to explain shift operation:

```
unsigned char bits = 1;     // '10011011' is the corresponding bit pattern
bits << 1;                  // left shift
```

My head spin a little when i looked at this, where is '10011011' coming from? '1' is not '0x01'?

Another question comes from http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/ptralign.html, where author try to unpack structure:

```
struct mystruct {
    char c;
    long int i32;
    int i16;
} s;
```

using

```
unsigned char *p = buf;

s.c = *p++;

s.i32 = (long)*p++ << 24;
s.i32 |= (long)*p++ << 16;
s.i32 |= (unsigned)(*p++ << 8);  // this line !
s.i32 |= *p++;

s.i16 = *p++ << 8;
s.i16 |= *p++;
```

My question is, p is a pointer to unsigned char(which is 8 bits), right? when building higher bytes of s.i32(24~31, 16~23), *p++ is converted to 'long'(32bits) before doing left shift, so left shift would not lose bit in *p++, but in

```
s.i32 |= (unsigned)(*p++ << 8);
```

*p++ is shifted first, then convert to unsigned int, wouldn't the bits of *p++ all lost during the shift?

Again i realize i maybe missing some of the basics in C here. Hope someone can give a hand here.

Thanks,

Comment: And the character `'1'` would be 0x31 = 00110001, so can't be that.

Comment: For the first one, did you check the errata (what edition)? (there are often mistakes in these type of books)

Comment: it's the 4th edition. i'll check if any errata online. thanks.

Comment: @user1559625: It's in the [errata](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780201721485/Errata/Lippman_0201721481_Errata.html): `Page 155: In the example at the bottom of the page the initializer for bits should be 0233, not 1.`

Comment: Thanks Jesse! That makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your second question, performing **any** arithmetic operation on a `char` promotes it to a (possibly unsigned) `int` (including shifting and other bitwise operations), so the integer-size value is shifted, not the 8-bit char value.

Comment: More precisely, you need to control the promotion to the type you want *before* the bit shift; not after.

Comment: @CraigNelson yes, regarding sign-extended/unsigned.

Comment: exactly. That was what I was trying to get across to him (you clearly already knew =P)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the bit pattern of 1 is 0x01. 10011011 is the bit pattern for decimal 155.

As for the shifts, you're missing something called the "integral promotions", which are performed in arithmetic and binary operations like shifts. In this case, there's an `unsigned char` operand (`*p++`) and an `int` operand (the constant), so the `unsigned char` operand is converted to `int`. The cast (whether to `long` or to `unsigned int`) is always performed **after** the promotion and the shift are performed. So no, in none of the shifts are all of the bits lost.